# Do I still need babel with NodeJs5?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

As far as I know node 5 supports ES2015, but when I try to run something like

```
import sizeOf from 'image-size';
```

I get

```
$>  node -v
v5.9.0
$> node test.js
/Users/dev/tmp/test.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import sizeOf from 'image-size';
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import 
...
```

Now, when I search google, I find suggestions using babel
(using a .babelrc with an es2015 preset), but if node5 supports ES2015, why do I need babel ?

Comment: You can check here what is supported and what is not https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#node5

Comment: nice page, but `import` is not even mentioned :(

Comment: I guess babel-node (babel-cli) is a good solution here ?

Comment: @JeanlucaScaljeri: There's a list of ES6 features currently available in Node here: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/. The module syntax is in fact not supported yet. But yes, you're on the right lines, babel-node will convert your `import` statements to `require()` calls.

Comment: Please read tag descriptions! [tag:babel] is not the right tag.

Comment: Good point, I didn't expect that :) I've updated the post

Answer (score 1):

> if node5 supports ES2015, why do I need babel

Node doesn't support every feature of ES2015 yet. For the unsupported features you might want to use Babel, or simply not use the feature.

Comment: If you want to transpile less you can search npm for a preset that removes transforms supported in your node version. example "babel-preset-node5"